# EC2 Tomcat crashes each morning

Tags: amazon-ec2, tomcat, tomcat7

I am preparing to launch a new web application and I have an EC2 instance, running Ubuntu 12.04, with Tomcat 7.0.4.29. For the last two mornings it has crashed at around 8am. There is no error in my Tomcat logs to suggest my web app has crashed (and it is not public yet anyway).

This question is very similar to this unanswered one from 2011:
https://serverfault.com/questions/287461/apache2-and-tomcat-6-crashing-each-morning

I don't think Tomcat is the cause. What else could it be? How can I best diagnose this problem?

Comment: Any information in the system logs, such as killed by the oom killer?

Comment: Seeing this is an EC2 - probably a small instance - my guess would be, without further info, this is a system problem, not tomcat. As suggested by 3molo, check on the system logs (messages, dmesg...) and look for an automated killer like oom. Also, set alerts for the monitoring system for memory and cpu, that could give you a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it was the system oom killer. There is a cron job that runs that updates all the apt-packages.

I resolved the issue by removing the cron job.